# Does $\mathbb{N}$ have fewer primes than any arithmetic progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

Let $f(x):=ax+b$ for naturals $x,a,b$, such that $f(x)$ will take infinitely many primes as $x\to\infty$.

Is it the case that for any choice of $a,b$, there exists some $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $\pi(n)<\pi_{a,b}(n)$?

In other words, in the limit, do the naturals yield fewer primes than all admissible arithmetic progressions? This seems likely to be true heuristically, but it's non-obvious to me past that.

Comment: By Chebotarev $\pi_{a,b}(n)$ is asymptotically $1/a\pi(n)$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the first $n$ terms of $\{ax+b\}$, then yes.
For example, primes among the odd numbers are more common than primes among the integers.
They are all squeezed into series with b that are coprime to $a$. That increases the density by a factor $a/\phi(a)$.
On the other hand, numbers are larger by a factor $a$, so primes become rarer by a factor $(\ln n)/(\ln an)$.
This second factor approaches $1$, so eventually the $a/\phi(a)$ dominates, and each sub-sequence has more primes than the full sequence.

Comment: So every distinct value of $a$ corresponds to a unique prime density in the limit?